# How to reference a python file located in a local <repo>.git directory without using relative reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, airflow

I cloned a private repo locally using git-sync resulting in all of my repo files under the following path:

```
/home/airflow/<repo>.git
```

Within that git repo, I have a python file "x.py" (which is a DAG) under the following path:

```
/home/airflow/<repo>.git/dags/x.py
```

Similarly, I have another python file "y.py" (a custom operator) under the following path:

```
/home/airflow/<repo>.git/plugins/operators/y.py
```

My question is:
how do I reference a function from file "y.py" in file "x.py" ?

I tried adding the following import to "x.py"
`from /home/airflow/<repo>.git/plugins/operators/y import HelloOperator`
which resulted in there being a syntax error b/c of the ".git"

I also tried adding the following import to "x.py"
`from /home/airflow/<repo>.plugins.operators.y import HelloOperator`
which resulted in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<repo>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set your [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable correctly:

- if this code is for your own usage only, you may set any path you see fit in your PYTHONPATH:

```
# for example, if you choose to set the root of the project:
export PYTHONPATH=/home/airflow/<repo>.git:$PYTHONPATH

# you should be able to write:
from plugins.operators.y import HelloOperator
```

- if you need to publish this code and share it with others, just check the doc of this project to see how plugins should be set -- perhaps this project implies to run with a PYTHONPATH which includes the `plugins/` directory, or ...

Comment: Thanks, I did have "/home/airflow" as part of the python path but changing it to "/home/airflow/<repo>.git" seemed to make it work!